# Previous batches appending in Spark structured streaming 2.2.0 where source is Kafka

Tags: scala, apache-spark, redis, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using spark structured streaming 2.2.0 with Kafka as source and Redis as sink to be used as cache. The cache should be filled with latest data only so. But the issue is whenever I'm getting new batches, it keeps appending with previous ones and getting stored which is wrong. I only need current batch to be stored.

The next batches are just the updated version of the previous ones. So I've tried using "update" as outputMode. But its not working as expected.

Is there anything else I can try ? Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

I've added `Trigger.ProcessingTime("1 second")` - it seems to work when I use the console as format. But in redis, the data is still appending.

Comment: Where is it appending, in Redis?

Comment: Yes, in redis.
I'm using KVs, on every batch the key is same so it should update the values. But the values stored include the values from previous batches also. I've tried deleting the key before storing the current batch. But it still not working. So I'm guessing the problem is in spark/kafka instead.